# No Data Shown On JQGrid

Tags: c#, jquery-plugins, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm fairly new to MVC and Jquery. for last couple of days I was trying to use Jqgrid http://www.trirand.com/blog/ to show data in my database. I use EF Code first to create my only class 'Author'

```
public class Author
{

    public int AuthorID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string FullName
    {
        get
        {
            return  FirstName+ " "+LastName ;
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my 'AuthorController' which create Json data:

```
public ActionResult LinqGridData(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows)
{
    var jsonData = new
    {
         total = 5,
         page = 1,
         records = db.Authors.Count(),
         rows = db.Authors.Select(a => new
                                 {
                                   id = a.AuthorID,
                                   cell = new { a.AuthorID, a.FirstName, a.LastName }
                                 }
         )
     };
     return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I also tried different method to get my Json data:

```
 public ActionResult LinqGridData (string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows) 
   {
        var jsonData = new {
        total = 5, 
        page=1,
        records = db.Authors.Count(),
        rows = (from a in db.Authors
                select new 
                {
                    id = a.AuthorID,
                    cell = new {  a.AuthorID, a.FirstName, a.LastName }
                }
          )
      };
      return Json(jsonData,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

and here is my JavaScript, which I use in my view:

```
 $(function () {
    $("#list").jqGrid({
        url: '/Author/LinqGridData',
        datatype:'json',
        mtype: 'GET',
        colNames:['Author ID', 'First Name', 'Last Name'],
        colModel:[
            {name:'AuthorID',index:'AuthorID',width:55 },
            {name:'FirstName',index:'FirstName',width:90 },
            {name:'LastName',index:'LastName',width:80,align:'right' }
        ],
        pager:'#pager',
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList:[5, 10, 20, 30],
        sortname:'AuthorID',
        sortorder:'desc',
        viewrecords:true,
        gridview:true,
        caption:'Author List'
    });
});
jQuery("#datagrid").jqGrid('navGrid', '#navGrid', { edit: true, add: true, del: true });
```

I can show the grid with dummy data. with this action method:

```
 public ActionResult GridData(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows)
   {
       var jsonData = new
       {
           total = 1, // we'll implement later 
           page = 1,
           records = 3, // implement later 
           rows = new[]
           {
              new {id = 1, cell = new[] {"1", "-7", "Is this a good question?"}},
              new {id = 2, cell = new[] {"2", "15", "Is that a good question?"}},
              new {id = 3, cell = new[] {"3", "23", "Why is the sky in the sky?"}}    
           }
       };
       return Json(jsonData,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
   }
```

the problem is whenever I want to show the data from my database, I only can show the grid itself not the data. 
I tried to convert the json data toList() or toArary() before sending to the view, same result. I hope I made myself clear.

any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try to use a tool like fiddler to check what json are being returned for the page, when trying to debug one error like this.

Comment: @Gabriel, I'm using Fiddler. I can see my Json data in Fiddler but not in the Jqgrid. grid is empty.

Comment: In your description the data that the code is returning to the jqgrid will be a lot usefull

Comment: @Gabriel, returned Json is correct, i checked with http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to show data from my db. the problem was in my query. i use this method for my action method:

```
public JsonResult LinqGridData (string sidx, string sord, int page, object rows)
   {
       var authors = (from a in db.Authors select a).ToList();
       var jsonData = new {
        total = 5, 
        page=1,
        records = db.Authors.Count(),
        rows = authors.Select(a => new 
                    {
                        id = a.AuthorID,
                        cell = new[] { a.AuthorID.ToString(), a.FirstName, a.LastName }
                    }
        )              
       };
      return Json(jsonData,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);            
    }
```

and i used this in my Javascript:

```
$(function () {
$("#list").jqGrid({
    url: "/Author/LinqGridData",
    datatype: "json",
    jsonReader: {
        root: "rows",
        page: "page",
        total: "total",
        records: "records",
        cell: "cell",
        id:"id"
    },
    mtype: "GET",
    colNames: ["Author ID", "First Name", "Last Name"],
    colModel: [
        { name: "AuthorID", key: true, width: 55 },
        { name: "FirstName", width: 80 },
        { name: "LastName", width: 100, align: "right" }
    ],
    pager: "#pager",
    rowNum: 10,
    rowList: [5, 10, 20],
    sortname: "AuthorID",
    sortorder: "desc",
    viewrecords: true,
    gridview: true,
    width: 610,
    height: 250,
    caption: "Author List"
});
```

});
jQuery("#list").jqGrid("navGrid", "#pager", { edit: true, add: true, del: true });

yes , you can omit the 'cell' attribute and reduce your json data. you can also put 'id':0 which normally means treat the first item as the id. i also used 'key' attribute, but it's redundant. you can also pass your query result as Array too. if anyone can tell me is there any benefit of using List over others would much appreciated.

Thanks for your help
good luck

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried jsonReader with "repeatitems: false" ?
For example:

```
$("#list").jqGrid({
    url: '/Author/LinqGridData',
    datatype:'json',
    jsonReader: {
        repeatitems: false
    },
    .....
```

UPDATE:
If you look at the response body returned from your LinqGridData method, it looks like this:

```
{"total":5,"page":1,"records":1,"rows":
  [
    {"id":"1","cell":{"AuthorID":"1","FirstName":"Mike","LastName":"Lee"}}, .....
  ]
}
```

But I think it should be like this:

```
{"total":5,"page":1,"records":1,"rows":
  [
    {"id":"1","cell":{"1", "Mike", "Lee"}}, .....
  ]
}
```

Actually this is your "dummy data" version's response body.

I'll post my working example below. In this example, I did not use 'cell' attribute. 
At server side:

```
        var myQuery = from t in db.Customers
                      select t;
        var jsonData = new
        {
            total = totalPages,
            page = pageNum,
            records = totalRecords,
            rows = myQuery.ToList()
        };

        return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

At client side:

```
{
    url: '@Url.Action("GetList")',
    datatype: 'json',
    jsonReader: {
      repeatitems: false
    },
    mtype: 'GET',
    colModel: [
      {
        name: 'CustomerID', label: 'ID', hidden: false, width: 40, sortable: true
      },
      {
        name: 'CompanyName', label: 'Company', width: 100, align: 'center' 
      },
    ]
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, when i tried jsonReader even that dummy data doesn't show up. my jsonReader is: jsonReader: {
                root:"rows",
                page:"page",
                total:"total",
                records:"records",
                repeatitems:false,
                cell:"cell",
                id:"id",
                userdata:"userdata",
            }

Comment: i'm the least in this communinty but I think your code is wrong. you don't specify what you select from your query?! the shape of your Json data is depend on your JsonReader. if you defined not to have anything for'cell' then you can have it without explicitly say 'cell:...'. here's a funny thing, whenever i add JsonReader to my JS, even that dummy data doesn't show up. my JsonReader is: jsonReader{root:"rows",page:"page",total:"total",                            records:"records",repeatitems:false,cell:"cell",id:"id",}. i don't know where my problem is? thaks for you help anyway.

Comment: Sorry, I deleted one line of code accidentally. Just added it. And I think you don't need 'cell'. The data format that returned from your LinqGridData must match the jqGrid settings defined in your view.

Comment: One more thing: did you check the json data returned from your LinqGridData method? What do they look like?